# Selectively Export Class Members in Qt-based Library

Tags: c++, qt, dll, linker

In an effort to optimize the binary of a Qt-based dynamic library, I'm attempting to *selectively* export a number of relevant methods from classes that inherit from `QObject` *and* use `moc` to define custom signals and slots, instead of exporting them entirely (all of their members). Some sample code is below.

```
#ifdef LIB_BUILD
    #define LIB_SHARED Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
    #define LIB_SHARED Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class C: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    LIB_SHARED void f();
    /* ... */

public slots:
    LIB_SHARED void g();

private:
    void h();

private slots:
    void i();
};
```

**The idea:** since `h()` and `i()` are private (and no inline method call any of these functions), there is no need to export these symbols, since they will be used by the library alone. On the other hand, `f()` and `g()` are members eligible for exporting, so they're explicitly marked for that.

**The problem:** the `Q_OBJECT` macro declares a couple of virtual method overrides for methods in `QObject`, and these methods are *not* exported (since the macro will expand to declarations not containing `LIB_SHARED` or `Q_DECL_EXPORT`). Thus, the virtual table will be incomplete in client code.

**The (un)solution:** apply `LIB_SHARED` to the entire class, as it is typically suggested:

```
class LIB_SHARED C: public QObject { /* ... */ };
```

This solves linking problems, but the primary goal (eliminating unnecessary export table entries) is not reached, at least not for `QObject`-based classes.

**The question:** is there any way to achieve the desired result? I've tried messing a bit around the `Q_OBJECT` macro, with no success.

I hope for a solution that works on Linux systems too (assuming hidden symbol visibility as default), so `.def` files are not applicable. Hacks, however, are welcome :)

Any help is appreciated.

PS: Note that besides this problem is framed in a Qt environment, it can happen anywhere where a macro expansion is used to generate declarations, as in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use pimpl idiom and export only public part. For example:

```
class CPrivate;
class LIB_SHARED C: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
private: 
    CPrivate* m_private;
public:
    ...
};
```

And create private class where placed all private (non exportable) stuff:

```
class CPrivate : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void h();

public slots:
    void i();
}
```

Then initialize and call private implementation from public class.